# .ajax get keep data keep coming null in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am trying to use this following function to get some data.

```
function SaveData() {
            var value = $('#tblRadio').find('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
            url: '/home/IsEmployeeVoted',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result); // shows whole dom
                if (parseInt(result) > 0) {
                    $('div.dvVoteWrapper').removeAttr('style');
                    $('div.popupArea').removeAttr('style');
                }
                else {
                    window.location = '/home/EmployeeVote?regoinID='+ value;
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Sorry, The requested property could not be found.");
            }
        });
        }
```

The controller function:

```
public ActionResult EmployeeVote(string regionID)
 {
 }
```

regionId keep coming null to me though the value variable have some value in javascript. any ideas ??

Comment: url: '/home/IsEmployeeVoted'+value, might helps a lot...

Comment: @ankur what is the url of your browser when you have hit the controller action ?

Comment: @DipeshParmar you  have missed out a forwardslash after controlleraction in url

Comment: you want to post data to wrong action. Ajax url : `/home/IsEmployeeVoted` , but your controller action `/home/EmployeeVote` , these are different. This is your problem.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi yes you were correct i had already changed that and did not edited the question now  i have edited the question my url in browser is "http://localhost:62793/home/EmployeeVote?regoinID=1" but still in the function the value in null instead of 1

Comment: @ankur Check the spelling of QueryString in url, that doesnot match with the parameter in the controller action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
data: 'regionID=' + value,
```

to

```
data: {regionID: value},
```

You need to pass the data as an object literal. Another option (which I dont recommend), which is closer to your idea:

```
url: '/home/IsEmployeeVoted?regoinID=' + value,
```

But if you want this to work you would need to remove the `type: 'POST'` (since GET is the default type).

Comment: @ankur You haven't changed the `data`. At least not in your code above.

Comment: your ajax url is url: `/home/IsEmployeeVoted`, but controller action is this: `/home/EmployeeVote` , so you try to post data to first action, not second. Ajax post Url and controller action url must be same... This is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Few issues:

```
var value = $('#tblRadio').find('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
```

I'd make sure that `value` is not undefined/null.

use `alert(value)` before the ajax call.

Also you are specifying `GET` but `POSTING` data to the server.

You could also wrap the regionId inside a javascript object, for instance.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { regionID: value },
            url: '/home/IsEmployeeVoted',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data); // shows whole dom
                if (parseInt(data) > 0) {
                    $('div.dvVoteWrapper').removeAttr('style');
                    $('div.popupArea').removeAttr('style');
                }
                else {
                    window.location = "/home/EmployeeVote";
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Sorry, The requested property could not be found.");
            }
        });
```

Comment: i have changed it to Post to still null is coming, i have put alert(value) it has value......

Comment: @ankur - try wrapping it in an object literal like I've shown in my example.  And ensure your value variable contains a value.

Comment: @ankur use fiddler2 to see whats getting passed up